# How to use LESS preprocessor in React Create-React-APP

Tags: css, reactjs, less, create-react-app

I want to use LESS preprocessor in my create-react-app.

```
React Code
ReactDOM.render(
    <form>
        <input type="email" data-info="Enter Email" pattern="/\S+@\S+\.\S+/" required title="Please enter value" required="required"/>
        <input type="submit"/>      
    </form>
    ,document.getElementById('root'))
```

index.less

```
body{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Here is the way I am doing it**

You should use node-sass-chokidar npm package:

```
npm install node-sass-chokidar --save-dev
```

Then add the following to your npm scripts in package.json :

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
```

The watcher will find every Sass file in src subdirectories, and create a corresponding CSS file next to it.

Remember to remove all css files from the source control and add src/**/*.css to your .gitignore.

Finally you might want to run watch-css automatically with npm start, and run build-css as a part of npm run build . For it, install the following npm package in order to be able to execute two scripts sequentially:

```
npm install --save-dev npm-run-all
```

Then change your npm start and build scripts in package.json file to the following:

```
   "scripts": {
     "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
     "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   }
```

See this link for further information: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Comment: Thank You for your response.Currently i use SASS in my app but i want to use LESS. so what the npm package install and what is script i add to package for LESS .

Comment: Thank you for this answers! It worked exactly the same with replacing sass with less :)  -- and yes there is a node-less-chokidar package on npm

Comment: As of October 2018, with the release of create-react-app v2.x, sass is supported out of the box:  [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-sass-stylesheet)

Answer (score 2):

With create-react-app 2 you can use "Create React App Configuration Override" (craco) and craco-less to configure this:

set up craco:

```sh
npm install @craco/craco
```

in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
```

setting up craco for less:

```
npm install craco-less
```

create new file: craco.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require('craco-less'),
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion. If would like to use Ant Design, need more config: https://github.com/DocSpring/craco-less

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and painless way to add less support with reactjs app by far is to use `custom-react-scripts` with `create-react-app` for LESS/SASS/decorators support :

Install: `npm install -g create-react-app custom-react-scripts`

Create app:
    `create-react-app <app_name> —scripts-version custom-react-scripts`

Example less file:

```
.myDiv{ background: gray; }
```

and then in your component:

```
import lessStyles from '<less file path>';

<div style={lessStyles.myDiv}>
  ...
</div>
```

or the regular way:

```
import '<less file path>';

<div className="myDiv">
  ...
</div>
```

For reference:

https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts

https://github.com/fawaz-ahmed/fawaz-ahmed.github.io

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem.
Just include the following lines into your webpack configuration rules section ([taken from the official less loader examples](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#examples)):

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
    }, {
      loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
    }]
  },
```

Of course, you need to add respective packages into your package.json

And then in you code simply import needed styles

```
import './style.less'
```

Using such approach you won't introduce an extra step of creating additional css files.